# Mean and standard deviation after a coin is tossed

Tags: standard-deviation, means

Could someone help solve this?

Let **X** equal the number of heads when $3600$ coins are tossed.

Find the Mean and Standard Deviation of **X**

Comment: ["Binomial distribution"?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your understanding of the problem? Do you understand the concepts involved (mean, std)?

Comment: to be honest i am a little lost, been out of class for a few weeks now and i'm unsure as to what i'm doing. i know there is a 1/2 chance to receive heads when flipping a coin so i'm assuming 1600 would be the amount of heads. I know how to compute mean and standard deviation, but after i get a set of numbers.

Comment: @J.Gee I may sound like I'm repeating myself, but have you heard of the Binomial distribution?

Comment: No, but i am reading on it right now.

Comment: As i was reading on it, i was beyond confused. I am taking a basic course of statistics. We are learning basic things, and using simple equations and variables. I compared some of my notes with the information, and i would see two separate things but sort of similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume each coin toss is independent. Let each of the 3600 outcomes be numbered, so that you have 3600 independent Bernoulli random variables $X_1,\dots, X_{3600}$ (where $X_i$ equals 1 if the $i$-th coin toss is Heads, and $0$ otherwise).

In particular, for all $1\leq i\leq 3600$, we have $\mathbb{P}\{X_i=1\} = \frac{1}{2}$ (the coins are fair), and $$X = \sum_{i=1}^{3600} X_i.$$

You have that $X$ follows a Binomial$(3600,1/2)$ distribution. If you do not know what it is, let's use the following two facts:

- $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=\mathbb{P}\{X_i=1\} = \frac{1}{2}$ for all $i$, and *expectation is linear*:
  $$
  \mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{3600} X_i\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{3600} \mathbb{E}[X_i] = 3600\cdot \frac{1}{2} = 1800.$$
- Variance is *not* linear, but the variance of a sum of *independent* random variables is the sum of their variances:
  $$
  \operatorname{Var}[X]=\operatorname{Var}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{3600} X_i\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{3600} \operatorname{Var}[X_i] = 3600\cdot \frac{1}{4} = 900.$$
  Where we used that the $X_i$'s are independent, and that the variance of a Bernoulli(1/2) ("a fair coin") random variable $Z$ is
  $$
  \operatorname{Var}[Z]= \mathbb{E}[Z^2]-\mathbb{E}[Z]^2 = \mathbb{E}[Z] - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{4}$$
  where in the middle  we relied on the fact that since $Z$ only can take values either $0$ or $1$, we have $Z^2 = Z$.

---

Takeaway: this problem can be modeled by a Binomial$(n,p)$ distribution, where $n=3600$ and $p=1/2$: since you sum 3600 *independent* coin tosses with *same* probability of Heads (here, 1/2). In general, if $Y$ follows a Binomial$(n,p)$ distribution, we have $\mathbb{E}[Y] = np$ and $\operatorname{Var}Y = np(1-p)$.